# BruteForceMedian algorithm appears to have a quadratic efficiency. (Why?)

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, brute-force, selection-sort

This algorithm appears to have a quadratic efficiency. (Why?)

Answer (score 1):

To analyze complexity, you just have to count the number of operations.

Here, there are two nested loops:

```
for i in 0 to n – 1 do
    for j in 0 to n – 1 do
        operation() // Do something
    done
done
```

With i = 0, `operation` will be ran for all j in [0,n-1] that is n times. Then increment i, and repeat until i > n-1. That is the `operation` is ran `n*n` times in the worst case.

So in the end, this codes does `n^2` operations, that's why it has quadratic efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trick question, it appears to be both n^2 and 2^n at the same time depending on the whether the if statement on line j is executed.

Comment: There is no re-indexing, so where do you see the exponential ?